# How to create a relationship between winning difference and probability of winning

Tags: handball

I am trying this for different sports, but to illustrate my problem I will use Basketball as an example.
I want to crate a statistical relationship between the Spread ( or Handicap ) and the Money Line ( or probability of winning ). And I wish to do this by using data.
In short, I want to know what should be the probability of winning if one team better than the other by 1, 2, 3, etc points.
For basketball, usually its used the normal distribution as an approximation of the behaviour of such relationship, but once more, I wanted to use just data.

Could anyone give some lights on how to go about it?

Using ChatGPT, it suggested using Logistic Regression, but I don't believe it works, understanding the principles and logic of such regression. But maybe I am wrong.